# How to insert image into the Settings Page of a Plugin?

Tags: plugins, php

I'm trying to insert an image from the plugin folder (I've created) so it can be displayed on the Settings Page.

- I can't hard code it because the Wordpress doesn't always get installed on the main domain.
- I don't want to host the image externally

So that leaves me with a way to call the plugins URL using PHP. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this? I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
<img src="<?php SOMETHING() ?>/plugin_folder/logo.png">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`plugin_dir_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) "gets the URL (with trailing slash) for the plugin `__FILE__` passed in".

```
<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>logo.png">
```